# Convert my my variable into a 12/12 time format using moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I need to convert my time that is in military time 24 hours time to regular 12/12 time.

```
nextArrivalFinal2 = ((hour > 0 ? hour + ":" + (min < 10 ? "0" : "") : "") + min + ":" + (sec < 10 ? "0" : "") + sec);
console.log("nextArrival2", typeof nextArrivalFinal2)
console.log("nextArrival2", nextArrivalFinal2)

var convertedDate = moment(new Date(nextArrivalFinal2));
console.log('converted1', convertedDate)
console.log('converted', moment(convertedDate).format("hh:mm:ss"));
```

`nextArrivalFinal2` displays the time as a string in `HH:MM:ss` format. But when I plug it into the moment js, it says it is an `invalid date`.

Comment: If you are using moment.js, why are you using the Date constructor to parse the string? Use moment.js for parsing (and tell it the format). 24 hour format is used by many organisations and individuals other than military. ;-)

Comment: `new Date("11:22:33")` is Invalid. For a date to be valid, it should include the day, month and year.

Answer (score 2):

You are not parsing the time with moment.js, the line:

```
var convertedDate = moment(new Date(nextArrivalFinal2));
```

is using the date constructor to parse a string like "13:33:12", which will likely return an invalid date in every implementation (and if it doesn't, it will return something that may be very different to what you expect).

Use moment.js to parse the string and tell it the format, e.g.

```
var convertedDate = moment(nextArrivalFinal2, 'H:mm:ss'));
```

Now you can get just the time as:

```
convertedDate().format('h:mm:ss a');
```

However, if all you want is 24 hr time reformatted as 12 hour time, you just need a simple function:

```js
// 13:33:12
/* Convert a time string in 24 hour format to
** 12 hour format
** @param {string} time - e.g. 13:33:12
** @returns {sgtring} same time in 12 hour format, e.g. 1:33:12pm
*/
function to12hour(time) {
  var b = time.split(':');
  return ((b[0]%12) || 12) + ':' + b[1] + ':' + b[2] + (b[0] > 12? 'pm' : 'am');
}

['13:33:12','02:15:21'].forEach(function(time) {
  console.log(time + ' => ' + to12hour(time));
});
```